# F# if statement function with parameter syntax

Tags: if-statement, compilation, f#

The issue is: I cannot figure out what the error is refering to when it diplays

Here is the error:
*source_file.fs(10,5): error FS0010: Unexpected keyword 'if' in binding. Expected '=' or other token.*

And I've been researching this error and proper syntax for a good while.

Now what I want to do, I hope, is obvious from the general look of the program.

Knowing the correct syntax would be great as microsofts docs are not great.

Seeing as this is case, I just don't understand what could be wrong.

```
open System

let one = "one"
let two = "two"

if oneortwo one then printfn one + " 1"
else printfn two + " 2"

let oneortwo(a : string)
    if a = "one" then return true
    elif a = "two" then return false

return false
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

F# is an expression based language, which means that everything has a value (returns something). F# is also statically typed, so everything returned is of a specific type.

Since everything is an expression, the `return` keyword is not used. The final expression in a function body is the returned value.

This goes also for `if ... then ... else`: every branch must return a value and be of the same type.

The correct syntax for your function is

```
let oneortwo a =
    if a = "one" then true
    else false
```

An excellent source of learning F# is Scott Wlaschin's site [F# for fun and profit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/)

Comment: Ah I see, the error was throwing me astray, I never even looked at the function as the problem. Okay now that it is fixed I will work through all the other errors in the program. Thanks for the speedy reply!

Comment: I'll just point out that in this particular case the function could be simplified down to `let oneortwo = (=) "one"` :P